# Symfony: Create new entity inside doctrine EntityListener with ManyToOne association

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to record every change in quantity of a given item. For that purpose, I listen for a change of an **Item** entity and wish to create a new **Transaction** instance with details about the action. So I'm creating an entity inside a listener.

I've set up everything according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) and created the listener based on [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/faep/listening-on-an-entity-with-an-entity-listener) example.

The code (I believe) is relevant for my problem is following.

**ItemListener**

```
// ...
private $log;
/** @ORM\PreUpdate */
public function preUpdateHandler (Item $item, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $changeSet = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($item)['quantity'];
    $quantityChange = $changeSet[1] - $changeSet[0];

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setItem($item);
    $transaction->setQuantityChange($quantityChange);

    $this->log = $transaction;
}

/** @ORM\PostUpdate */
public function postUpdateHandler(Item $item, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($this->log);
    $em->flush();
}
```

This works perfectly. However, the problem is when I add another field to the transaction entity. The *user* field inside **Transaction** entity has ManyToOne relation. Now when I try to set the user inside the `preUpdateHandler`, it leads to and undefined index error inside the `UnitOfWork` function of the Entity Manager.

```
Notice: Undefined index: 000000003495bf92000000001108e474
```

The listener is now like this. I retreive the user based on the token that was sent with the request. Therefore, I inject the request stack and my custom user provider in the listener's constructor. I do not think this is the source of the problem. However, if necessary, I'll edit the post and add all the remaining code (rest of the listener, services.yaml and user provider).

**ItemListener**

```
// ...
private $log;
/** @ORM\PreUpdate */
public function preUpdateHandler (Item $item, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $changeSet = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($item)['quantity'];
    $quantityChange = $changeSet[1] - $changeSet[0];

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setItem($item);
    $transaction->setQuantityChange($quantityChange);

    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $company = $this->userProvider->getUserByRequest($request);

    $this->log = $transaction;
}

/** @ORM\PostUpdate */
public function postUpdateHandler(Item $item, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($this->log);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I do not understand why retreiving the flush with retrieval of another entity leads to that error. When searching for an answer I found that that many recommend not to use `flush()` inside the `postUpdate` cycle but rather in `postFlush`. However, this method is not defined for Entity listeners according to the documentation and if possible, I'd like to stick to such a listener and not an event listener.

Thank you for any help. I also include the transaction entity code just in case.

**Transaction Entity**

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use App\DoctrineUtils\MagicAccessors;
  use App\Entity\T\TIdentifier;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="transaction")
 */
 class Transaction
 {
  use TIdentifier;
  use MagicAccessors;

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
  */
  public $item;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", length=14, precision=4, nullable=false)
  */
  public $quantityChange;


  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
  */
  private $createdTime;

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
  */
  private $user;


  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->createdTime = new \DateTime();
  }

  /**
  * @param mixed $quantityChange
  */
  public function setQuantityChange(int $quantityChange): void
  {
    $this->quantityChange = $quantityChange;
  }

  /**
  * @param mixed $createdTime
  */
  public function setCreatedTime($createdTime): void
  {
    $this->createdTime = $createdTime;
  }

  /** @ORM\PrePersist **/
  public function onCreate() : void
  {
    $this->setCreatedTime(new \DateTime('now'));
  }

  public function setUser(?User $user): self
  {
    $this->user= $user;

    return $this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [bundle](https://github.com/DamienHarper/DoctrineAuditBundle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that another instance of the entity manager was instantiated in the `getUserByRequest()` function, where I log that the user's token was used. Apart others, I created inside it a new manager, persisted the entry and flushed the result. However, the new entity manager does not know about the unit of work inside the other entity manager inside the listener. Hence the undefined index error.

I tried to omit the persist and the flush part inside the user getter function, but that was not enough. In the end I solved the problem by passing the given instance entity manager from inside the listener to the getter function. So basically, I ended up calling this from the `preUpdateHandler` function inside the listener.

```
$em = $args->getEntityManager();
$company = $this->userProvider->getUserByRequest($request, $em);
```

Hope this helps if you find yourself in a similar pickle.